# Aligning Footer Content

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am learning bootstrap. At this time, I'm trying to add a footer to my page. I need my footer to look like this:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
| Hello               Thank you for visiting               [logo] |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Basically, the idea is to have three sections. The content in the first is left aligned. The content in the second is centered. Finally, the content in the third is right aligned. In an attempt to do this, I did the following:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-static-top navbar-dark bg-inverse">
  <span class="navbar-brand">Hello</span>
  <span class="center-block"><span class="center-text">Thank you for visiting</span></span>
  <span class="pull-right"><div class="pull-right">[logo]</div></span>                  
</nav>
```

Unfortunately, this does not work. The content does not appear on the same line (its all jagged, I was hoping for it be vertically centered). Also, the "Thank you for visiting" is not centered. It is left justified.

I'm not sure what I"m doing wrong.

Comment: Why using `navbar navbar-static-top navbar-dark bg-inverse` class.? Simply use `col-md-4` in  a `row` will output same as your given example.
To center text use `text-center` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello use this code this works perfect. Make sure that you add the bootstrap js and css files.

```
    <footer class="navbar navbar-static-bottom navbar-default">
              <div class="container" style="width">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                  <div class="navbar-brand" style="padding-left:0px; !important;color:#555 !important;">
                    Hello
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="navbar-header">
                  <div class="navbar-brand" style="position:absolute;text-align:center;width:1000px;">
                    Welcome to my website
                  </div>
                </div>
                   <div class="navbar-header navbar-right">
                  <div class="navbar-brand">
                    Logo goes here
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </footer>
```

Enjoy....!

Comment: When I tried it the "Welcome to my website" part was not centered. In addition, there was an extra `</a>` that was not needed. I don't understand why the "Welcome to my website" part is not centered.

Comment: Change the width in the style tag, for example i have used 1000px it may differ for you.

Comment: Try giving the value in % example. width:80%; this will allow your page to adjust according to the screen size automatically..

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why you are using `nav` but this solution might work for you:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4 text-left">
            <p>Hello</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 text-center">
            <p>Thank you for visiting</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 text-right">
            <p>[logo]</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm using a `nav` and `navbar` because I want my footer to be the same size as a `navbar` I have in the header for the sake of visual balance.